# Nodejs: How to write high performance async loop

Tags: node.js

have a initUrl, its an article which contains next blog, and defind `function getNextUrl(url, callback(err, nextUrl))`, want to get the next 100th url.

In stormjs (developing https://github.com/guileen/stormjs/issues/1), it write as

```
var url = initUrl;
for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
  url = getNextUrl(url, _);
}
console.log(url);
```

but what the best output should be, I want to know how noders write this code without 3rd module.

Comment: Won't the above code be automatically synchronous irrespective of whether you're calling async functions and callbacks or not?

Comment: @Denis he's using an async shorthand `_` is some kind of magic flow control thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = [];
(function recurse(url, i) {
    getNextUrl(url, function(err, nextUrl) {
        if (!err) {
            arr.push(nextUrl);
            if (i < 100) recurse(nextUrl, i++);
        }
    });
}("", 0);
```

I call this pattern boot strapped recursion.

If you prefer it to be more concise rather then efficient you can use some `.bind` magic.

```
(function recurse(i, err, url) {
    if (!err) arr.push(url);

    if (i < 100) getNextUrl(url, recurse.bind(null, ++i));
}(0, "trick it", url);
```

Comment: Can I drop the 3rd arguments urlarr

Comment: @guilin yes if you want to make it global.