# Nodejs: parallel request, serial response

Tags: concurrency, node.js

I have done [Nodejs: How to write high performance async loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069340/nodejs-how-to-write-high-performance-async-loop) for stormjs, you can check [stormjs serial loop demo](http://goo.gl/zxdrP)

but there is still have problem that parallel loop, e.g. we have a function `requestContext(index, callback(err, context))` which remote get context 'http://host/post/{index}',  and we need get the context of `[0-99]` and push context into an array in the order, `[context0...context99]`

but obviously this output cant work [stormjs parallel loop](http://goo.gl/TpLg9)

I still want to know how noders do this task, but you must make these requests parallel, not 1 by 1, it should be parallel request and serial push.

Comment: Why are you using storm for this? Why don't you just write it without storm.

Comment: i am not using storm for this, i am creating storm for this. i have to  make sure storm got the best code for this case, also similar case. and the question is just how to do it without stormjs.

Answer (score 1):

```
var counter = 0;
// create an array with numbers 0 to 99.

_.range(0,100).forEach(function(key, value, arr) {
    // for each of them request context
    requestContext(key, function(err, context) {
        // add the context to the array under the correct key
        if (!err) {
            arr[key] = context;
        }
        // increment counter, if all have finished then fire finished.
        if (++counter === 100) {
            finished(arr);
        }
    });
});

function finished(results) {
    // do stuff
}
```

No storm required. If you want an execution / flow control library I would recommend [Futures](https://github.com/coolaj86/futures) because it doesn't compile your code and "hides the magic".

Previously you recursed through each one and executed them in a serial order pushing them into the array in order.

This time you execute them all in parallel and tell each one to assign the right ordered key in the array to their own value.

[`_.range`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#range) Creates an array containing values 0 to 99.

Comment: thanks. why previous serial and this on parallel, because the code said. whether the next looping depends on previous lopping, will determine serial or parallel.

Comment: @guillin your previous example had each request returning an `url` that was needed for the next request. This time you have all 100 urls up front so you can just fire them in parallel.